# Using Meteor.users.update to update selected users data

Tags: meteor

I have code that stores and shows me the userID for a selected user on my leaderboard.

```
'click .player': function(){
  var playerId = this._id;
  Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
}
```

Using the code below (in the client) if they click a button called increment it should add 5 "threat" to the selected users threat... however it doesn't. I see it try and tick over but it goes back to the original number. (i'm assuming cause it's not on the server)

```
'click input.increment': function(){
  var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
  Meteor.users.update({_id: selectedPlayer}, {$inc: {'threat': 5}});
}
```

So I tried to change the click to this.

```
'click input.increment': function(){
  var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
  Meteor.call('incclick','selectedPlayer');
}
```

And put the code below in a method on the server using a meteor.call. Still the threat does not update.

```
incclick: function (selectedPlayer) {
  Meteor.users.update({_id: selectedPlayer}, {$inc: {'threat': 5}});
},
```

I am thinking it is either something about how I am using selectedPlayer in the _id: area. However I have tried a lot of things and looked around... not really sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Meteor.call('incclick','selectedPlayer');` you are passing 'selectedPlayer' as a string, not the variable.

Change it to `Meteor.call('incclick', selectedPlayer);`

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple. Thank you very much for that. It worked like a charm.